# How to add/replace attribute with set-aduser

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm running a script which will add or replace some attributes but im having an issue.
When i run this two command bellow, the first line it works but not the other one.

```
Set-aduser -identity $NewUser -Replace @{streetAddress="555 st."}
Set-aduser -identity $NewUser -Replace @{msRTCSIP-PrimaryAddress="SIP:Test.User@contoso.com"}
```

This attribute  *msRTCSIP-PrimaryAddress* contains "-" and it looks like they dont like it?

Any help will be appreciate

Comment: use quotes on that key or the parser will complain, `'msRTCSIP-PrimaryAddress' = ....`